# interesting question about subsequential limits

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $0,2$ are subsequential limits of $a_n$.
suppose that $\forall n\in \Bbb N: |a_{n+1} - a_n| < 1$.
Prove that $a_n$ has another subsequential limit, different from $0$ and $2$.

I coudn't solve this problem, can you please help me with the solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The sequence will have infinitely many terms between $\pm\frac12$.

Comment: but it could be that in all this infinite set of terms, every convergent sequence converges to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a$ is a subsequential limit of $(a_n)_n$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ the set $\{n~:~|a_n-a|<\varepsilon\}$ is infinite.

Now assume that $\{0,2\}$ is the set of all subsequential limits, then there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n\in\left(0-\frac12,0+\frac12\right)\cup\left(2-\frac12,2+\frac12\right)$ for all $n\geq N$.

If $a_N\in \left(0-\frac12,0+\frac12\right)$, then $a_{N+1}\in\left(0-\frac12,0+\frac12\right)$ since $|a_N-a_{N+1}|<1$. But induction we get $a_n\in\left(0-\frac12,0+\frac12\right)$ for all $n\geq N$. But then $2$ can't be a subsequencial limit.

If $a_N\in\left(2-\frac12,2+\frac12\right)$, then we get the same way that $0$ can't be a subsequential limit.

So $0$ and $2$ can't be the only subsequential limits.

Answer (score 0):

We shall construct a choice sequence $k\mapsto n_k$ such that $a_{n_k}\in J:=\bigl[{1\over2},{3\over2}\bigr]$ for all $k\geq1$. The subsequence $\bigl(a_{n_k}\bigr)_{k\geq1}$ then has a subsequential limit in this $J$, by Bolzano's theorem.

Put $n_0:=1$, and assume that $n_k\in{\mathbb N}$ has been chosen for some $k\geq0$. By assumption there is an $n'>n_k$ with $a_{n'}>{3\over2}$, and then there is an $n''>n'$ with $a_{n''}<{1\over2}$. As $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<1$ for all $n$ there has to be an  $n\in[n',n'']$ with $a_n\in J$. Let $n_{k+1}$ be the smallest such $n$.